# Insert into pg (массовая вставка данных в таблицу)

Tags: sql, postgresql

подскажите пожалуйста как заполнить таблицу данными массово

и почему у меня ошибка :(

```
Insert into services.card_blocks_fields (card_blocks_fieldsid, card_blocksid, field_name, name, sortorder, shortname, isvisible, isdeleted, data_typeid, width_value)
Values (1064, 62, 'cosid', 'ЦОС', 10, 'cosid', 1, 0, 1, 0)
Values (1065, 62, 'analiz_bazaid', 'Аналіз бази', 20, 'analiz_bazaid', 1, 0, 1, 0)
Values (1066, 62 'param1', 'param1', 30, 'param1', 0, 0, 6, 0)
Values (1067, 62 'block_name', 'block_name', 40, 'block_name', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1068, 62 'isbold', 'isbold', 50, 'isbold', 0, 0, 5, 0)
Values (1069, 62 'colored', 'colored', 60, 'colored', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1070, 62 'isempty', 'isempty', 70, 'isempty', 0, 0, 1, 0)
Values (1071, 62 'f_1', 'f_1', 80, 'f_1', 1, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1072, 62 'f_2', 'f_2', 90, 'f_2', 1, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1073, 62 'f_3', 'f_3', 100, 'f_3', 1, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1074, 62 'f_4', 'f_4', 110, 'f_4', 1, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1075, 62 'f_5', 'f_5', 120, 'f_5', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1076, 62 'f_6', 'f_6', 130, 'f_6', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1077, 62 'f_7', 'f_7', 140, 'f_7', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1078, 62 'f_8', 'f_8', 150, 'f_8', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1079, 62 'f_9', 'f_9', 160, 'f_9', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1080, 62 'f_10', 'f_10', 170, 'f_10', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1081, 62 'f_11', 'f_11', 180, 'f_11', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1082, 62 'f_12', 'f_12', 190, 'f_12', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1083, 62 'f_13', 'f_13', 200, 'f_13', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1084, 62 'f_14', 'f_14', 210, 'f_14', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1085, 62 'f_15', 'f_15', 220, 'f_15', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1086, 62 'f_16', 'f_16', 230, 'f_16', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1087, 62 'f_17', 'f_17', 240, 'f_17', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1088, 62 'f_18', 'f_18', 250, 'f_18', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1089, 62 'f_19', 'f_19', 260, 'f_19', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1090, 62 'f_20', 'f_20', 270, 'f_20', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1091, 62 'f_21', 'f_21', 280, 'f_21', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1092, 62 'f_22', 'f_22', 290, 'f_22', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1093, 62 'f_23', 'f_23', 300, 'f_23', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1094, 62 'f_24', 'f_24', 310, 'f_24', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1095, 62 'f_25', 'f_25', 320, 'f_25', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1096, 62 'f_26', 'f_26', 330, 'f_26', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1097, 62 'f_27', 'f_27', 340, 'f_27', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1098, 62 'f_28', 'f_28', 350, 'f_28', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1099, 62 'f_29', 'f_29', 360, 'f_29', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1100, 62 'f_30', 'f_30', 370, 'f_30', 0, 0, 4, 0)
Values (1101, 62 'f_31', 'f_31', 380, 'f_31', 0, 0, 8, 0)
Values (1102, 62 'f_32', 'f_32', 390, 'f_32', 0, 0, 8, 0)
Values (1103, 62 'f_33', 'f_33', 400, 'f_33', 0, 0, 8, 0)
Values (1104, 62 'f_34', 'f_34', 410, 'f_34', 0, 0, 8, 0)
Values (1105, 62 'f_35', 'f_35', 420, 'f_35', 0, 0, 8, 0)
Values (1106, 62 'f_36', 'f_36', 430, 'f_36', 0, 0, 8, 0)
Values (1107, 62 'f_37', 'f_37', 440, 'f_37', 0, 0, 8, 0)
Values (1108, 62 'f_38', 'f_38', 450, 'f_38', 0, 0, 8, 0)
Values (1109, 62 'f_39', 'f_39', 460, 'f_39', 0, 0, 8, 0)
Values (1110, 62 'f_40', 'f_40', 470, 'f_40', 0, 0, 8, 0)
Values (1111, 62 'sort_order', 'sort_order', 480, 'sort_order', 0, 0, 1, 0)

SELECT *
  FROM services.card_blocks_fields order by 1
  --where card_blocksid = '62'
```

Comment: VALUES пишется один раз, а дальше блоки данных в скобках через запятую. [Мануал-то посмотрите](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)... и примеры в нём. И не забывайте запятые между значениями.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into services.card_blocks_fields (card_blocks_fieldsid, card_blocksid, 
field_name, name, sortorder, shortname, isvisible, isdeleted, data_typeid, width_value)
Values 
(1064, 62, 'cosid', 'ЦОС', 10, 'cosid', 1, 0, 1, 0),
(1065, 62, 'analiz_bazaid', 'Аналіз бази', 20, 'analiz_bazaid', 1, 0, 1, 0),
(1066, 62 'param1', 'param1', 30, 'param1', 0, 0, 6, 0),
(1067, 62 'block_name', 'block_name', 40, 'block_name', 0, 0, 4, 0),
-------------------------------------------------------------------
(1068, 62 'isbold', 'isbold', 50, 'isbold', 0, 0, 5, 0);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]